# Error: expected mock function to have been called - onclick Jest enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

Not being able to get the following test to pass...
Sorry for putting up a lot of code....
I was able get some other click events working but I am stuck with this one at the moment

Getting the following message:

> "expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()
>
> expected mock function to have been called."

here is the click event under Render method

```
      className={!this.state.name || !this.state.label || this.state.valueStore === null ? `add-custom-field-button disabled` : `add-custom-field-button`}
          id="test-addclick"
          onClick={() => {this.onAddClick()}}
        >
          Create Field
        </button>
```

here is onAddClick method:

```
onAddClick = () => {
let obj = this.props.selectedFormJSON;

this.addValueAttribute().then(()=>{
  obj.FORM_COLUMN.push(
    {
      Control: this.state.control,
      CreateBy: this.props.user.userId,
      Datatype: this.state.datatype,
      Form_UID: this.props.selectedFormJSON.Form_UID,
      Help: this.state.help,
      ValueStore: this.state.valueStore
    }
  )
  this.props.updateSelectedFormJSON(obj);
  if(!this.props.isNewForm && this.state.valueStore) {
    this.props.patchForm().then((res)=>{
    if(res.Forms[0] && (res.Forms[0].Code === '200' || res.Forms[0].Code===200)) {
      toast(<div>Attribute Added Successfully!</div>, {type: toast.TYPE.SUCCESS,position: toast.POSITION.TOP_LEFT})
    } else {
      toast(<div>Failed to Add Attribute!</div>, {type: toast.TYPE.ERROR,position: toast.POSITION.TOP_LEFT})
    }
  });
  } else if(this.state.valueStore) {
    this.props.postForm().then((res)=>{
      if(res.Forms[0] && (res.Forms[0].Code === '201' || res.Forms[0].Code===201)) {
        toast(<div>Attribute Added Successfully!</div>, {type: toast.TYPE.SUCCESS,position: toast.POSITION.TOP_LEFT})
      } else {
        toast(<div>Failed to Add Attribute!</div>, {type: toast.TYPE.ERROR,position: toast.POSITION.TOP_LEFT})
      }
    })
  }
  this.props.closeModal();
})
}

     addValueAttribute = () => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if(this.state.valueStore) {
    let {valueTables, valueDatatypes, service} = this.state;
    let body = {
      Name: this.state.name,
      TableName: this.props.selectedFormJSON.Entity,
      Datatype: this.state.datatype,
      ChangeType: 'I'
    }
    fetch(service.URL+'/VALUE_ATTRIBUTE', { headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': service.subscription_key,
    },
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    })
    .then((res) => {
      res.status === 201 && resolve();
    })
    .catch(() => {
      reject();
    })
  } else {
    //Not a value attr
    resolve()
  }
})
```

}

Here is how I am trying to test it: using jest/enzyme. I have been using the same set up for some other click events and it has been working. Unable to figure out for the following:

```
it("should call onAddClick", async () => {  // use an async test method
baseProps. closeModal.mockClear();
baseProps. updateSelectedFormJSON.mockClear();

const instance = wrapper.instance();
const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'addValueAttribute');  // spy on addValueAttribute...
spy.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve())  // give any callbacks queued in PromiseJobs a chance to run
wrapper.find('#test-addclick').at(0).simulate('click');  // simulate click

expect(baseProps.updateSelectedFormJSON).toHaveBeenCalled();  // SUCCESS
expect(baseProps.closeModal).toHaveBeenCalled();  // SUCCESS
});
```

Comment: The problem is the call to `addValueAttribute.` As this is a promise jest don't wait for it. So the call for `toHaveBeenCalled` is called before the promise is resolved. Normally you solve such issues by mocking the promise call. Could you please show what happens inside of `addValueAttribute`?

Comment: its going to be a lot code but I updated the question

Comment: @AndreasKöberle updated !!

Comment: Looks like there is no easy way to mock this. Maybe you can try this solution: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting#unresolved-promises

Comment: I will give it a try -  thanks andreas

Answer (score 1):

`addValueAttribute` is expensive so you will want to mock it to resolve immediately. 
 `addValueAttribute` is a [class field](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) so you will need to mock it using the component instance.

When `onAddClick` is called it will call `this.addValueAttribute` which will be mocked to immediately return.  This will cause the `Promise` callback in `then` to get added to [the PromiseJobs queue](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues).  Jobs in this queue run *after the current message completes and before the next message begins*.

This means that the callback that calls `this.props.updateSelectedFormJSON` and `this.props.closeModal` is queued in the PromiseJobs queue when the click handler returns and the test continues.

At this point you need to pause your test to give the callback queued in PromiseJobs a chance to run.  The easiest way to do that is to make your test function `async` and call `await Promise.resolve();` which will essentially queue the rest of the test at the end of the PromiseJobs queue and allow any jobs already in the queue to run first.

Putting it all together, here is a simplified version of your code with a working test:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

class Comp extends React.Component {
  onAddClick = () => {
    this.addValueAttribute().then(() => {
      this.props.updateSelectedFormJSON();
      this.props.closeModal();
    })
  }
  addValueAttribute = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 100000);  // does something computationally expensive
    });  
  }
  render() {
    return (<button onClick={this.onAddClick}>Create Field</button>);
  }
}

it("should call onAddClick", async () => {  // use an async test method
  const props = {
    updateSelectedFormJSON: jest.fn(),
    closeModal: jest.fn()
  }
  const wrapper = shallow(<Comp {...props} />);
  const instance = wrapper.instance();
  const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'addValueAttribute');  // spy on addValueAttribute...
  spy.mockResolvedValue();  // ...and mock it to immediately resolve
  wrapper
    .find('button')
    .at(0)
    .simulate('click');  // simulate click
  await Promise.resolve();  // give any callbacks queued in PromiseJobs a chance to run
  expect(props.updateSelectedFormJSON).toHaveBeenCalled();  // SUCCESS
  expect(props.closeModal).toHaveBeenCalled();  // SUCCESS
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I solved somethind similar to it yesterday. I will look into it right now

Comment: spy.mockresolvedValue is not a function I am getting this as an answer

Comment: @usertestREACT `.mockResolvedValue()` was added in `Jest` version [22.2.0](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#jest-2220) so if you are using an earlier version of `Jest` use `.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve())` instead.

Comment: Brian thanks -  I am getting a different msg now  saying that expected mock function have been called  - error:   I will update my question / answer

Comment: @usertestREACT You are missing the `await Promise.resolve();` line after simulating the click.

Comment: Now I am facing a different error : which I had seen something similar but unable to locate the file.      Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: @usertestREACT Please update your code, I can't help with code I can't see

Comment: brian it goes back to  this.addValueAttribute().then(()=>{
   - it is posted on my question. I already added the promise and resolve as well

Comment: @usertestREACT if your latest code is in the question then you are still missing the `await Promise.resolve();` line after you simulate the click.  As for the error, are you sure it's the `then` chained from `this.addValueAttribute`?  Are you sure it's not coming from the `then` chained to either `this.props.patchForm()` or `this.props.postForm()`?

Comment: correct. I just  made a few things on patchForm and postForm, cannot read property 'then' of undefined. Working on it

Comment: Works perfect, only this answer on whole web, helped me to solve mocking async await.. There is so much content out there which is depracated.